# load() waits then refreshes X times

Tags: jquery, load, refresh

Basically, the code works; however, if I open another application or window then go back to index.html, the div that I refresh then reloads X * 60000, so if I have been away from that page for 5 mins it will fade in and out 5 times. Why is it doing that? I just want it to either do it once or just keep doing it in the background. Below is the code I use, which is very simple:

```
var auto_refresh_hccomps = setInterval(
function()
{
$('#hccomps').fadeOut('slow').load('widgets/habbcrazy/hccomps.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 60000);

<div id="hccomps"></div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using jQuery 1.6.0 or 1.6.1? if so, upgrade to 1.6.2. Or better yet, 1.7.2

Comment: Also of note, your .load is going to begin before it is done fading out and it will begin fading in regardless of it being done loading. However that has nothing to do with the effect you are seeing.

Comment: I am using 1.7.2/jquery.js and 1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js. I ended up changing this too:

    var refreshId_hccomps = setInterval(function() {
    var el = $("#hccomps");
    var req = $.get("widgets/habbcrazy/hccomps.php");
    el.fadeOut('slow', function () {
        req.done(function( data ){
            el.html(data).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
    }, 60000);

Seems to work fine now. Thanks.

Comment: @Keelan, if it works post it as your answer and accept it, so the question can be taken off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using 1.7.2/jquery.js and 1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js.

I ended up changing this to, does it a little different but works now.

```
var refreshId_hccomps = setInterval(function() { 
    var el = $("#hccomps"); 
    var req = $.get("widgets/habbcrazy/hccomps.php"); 
    el.fadeOut('slow', function () { 
        req.done(function( data ){ 
            el.html(data).fadeIn('slow'); 
        }); 
    }); 
}, 60000);
```

Seems to work fine now. Thanks.